# Metaplex candymachine whitelist and gatekeeper challenge not compatible

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

The title may be a bit misleading, but I'll try to explain what the problem is and the steps to reproduce.

**The Problem**

Whitelisted users (WL token holders) can't mint an NFT when the gatekeeper is enabled.
Error message: `Program returned error: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown`

Whitelist {burnEveryTime: true} && Gatekeeper: true are interfering with the mint process.

**I posted this question on the Metaplex discord server, and after discussions with Metaplex devs, we have decided to post it here to help users facing the same issue.**

If you are looking to enable `whitelist` functionality and the `gatekeeper` challenge for your CandyMachine-v2, then you may come across the issue of not being able to mint even with a WL token.

`config.json` looks like this:

```
{
"price": 0.1,
"number": 1500,
"gatekeeper": {
    "gatekeeperNetwork" : "ignREusXmGrscGNUesoU9mxfds9AiYTezUKex2PsZV6",
    "expireOnUse" : true
},
"solTreasuryAccount": "FYUfLoqD33rfsYGeEuisLGQhQiifGKrnjmcTQAyjQDUL",
"splTokenAccount": null,
"splToken": null,
"goLiveDate": "01 Jun 2022 00:00:00 GMT",
"endSettings": null,
"whitelistMintSettings": {
    "mode" : { "burnEveryTime": true },
    "mint" : "DJd3vbwoZgf6V5o9NdpxRVn82PKK7k7KQsRtU9VvjmoK",
    "presale" : true,
    "discountPrice" : null
},
"hiddenSettings": null,
"storage": "arweave-sol",
"ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
"ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
"awsS3Bucket": null,
"noRetainAuthority": false,
"noMutable": false
}
```

You may possibly even get an error message like this:
`Program returned error: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown`
Found in:
https://solscan.io/tx/4Qfxi9As8973AFQ3uCGqcPhvGhiEQdejsnvZ7MEfeGnyvddR4if5f1HKLPSx5S2Nf8w9Ybv4bWkooANwFTSMtrbY?cluster=devnet

Till now, you may have already guessed part of the problem with this configuration and probably thinking 'why the heck do you need a gatekeeper when your whitelist config has  `"burnEveryTime": true`'.

**The Solution**

In order to be able to work around this issue, it is best to disable the **gatekeeper** and proceed to mint without a gatekeeper challenge when your whitelist token will burnEveryTime.

This way, bots won't be able to do their thing since their WL token would burn after initial use.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. clone `metaplex` and do the initial setup and installation
2. Follow the steps in docs.metaplex
3. When reaching config.json step: enable gatekeeper and enable whitelisting with `burnEveryTime: true`
4. Deploy candymachine
5. Test through either `cli` or metaplex's front-end `candy-machine-ui`

Comment: you are right, those are incompatible. Maybe a github issue would be better suited though since you did not ask a question :)